# South Korea offline map

Tags: maps, here

I'm going to South Korea in a week and I wanted to download a map for offline use (data rates are quite prohibitive...).  Unfortunately, I can't find it anywhere. There are many Asian countries available, but Korea is nowhere to be found.

I'm running the latest available Windows Phone 8 version (8.0.10501.127) on a HTC 8S phone. Is this a bug? Am I missing something obvious? Are there any workarounds (alternatives?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it looks like South Korea is not available on HERE maps (and Japan neither!). Luckily there are some clients for [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/about) in the store that might give you what you need. The top contender seems to be [Offline Maps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/offline-maps/d4d858fc-698d-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8), though do also have a look at [GPS Navigator aSpass](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gps-navigator-aspass/829a6e3d-c88f-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8), [Simple OSM](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/simple-osm/9710865b-2c38-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) and [QuoVadis Mobile](http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/quovadis-mobile/d437752f-8034-4669-8b94-2eac8a1f77c3).

Comment: I can't help but notice that all of these are paid. Any free alternatives you would suggest?

Comment: @Tomasz As far as I can tell there are no free alternatives for Windows Phone.